# rewteet while using twitter api

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using Twitter Api 1.1, I want to retweet the status but can't successful. Please correct my code if find any mistake.

```
public function retweet($query, $full = FALSE){
        $res = $this->request('statuses/retweet', 'POST', is_array($query) ? $query : array($query)); }
```

Tweet send perfectly, favorite work perfectly but this cannot. Kindly correct mycode.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Nitek I am not get any error.

Comment: What is in `$query`?

Comment: @Terence $query means the id which api needs to retweet the status.

Comment: Can you update the question with the full code - it's hard to tell where the mistake is otherwise.